# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FormBuilder -> FormBuilder]: NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I am testing my angular code using Jasmine. I have imported everything but still getting errors. These are the 2 errors:

> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FormBuilder ->
> FormBuilder]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!

> Expected undefined to be truthy.

These errors are on multiple component. I have attached example of one component with these errors. How can I solve it ? (I am a beginner so please try to answer it in the simplest manner)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SortPipe } from './sort.pipe';
import { CustomPipeComponent } from './custom-pipe/custom-pipe.component';
import { CustpipeComponent } from './custpipe/custpipe.component';
import { RideFilterPipePipe } from './ride-filter-pipe.pipe';
import { ReactFormComponent } from './react-form/react-form.component';
import { TemplateDrivenFormComponent } from './template-driven-form/template-driven-form.component';
import { EmailValidator } from './template-driven-form/emailValidator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SortPipe,
    CustomPipeComponent,
    CustpipeComponent,
    RideFilterPipePipe,
    ReactFormComponent,
    TemplateDrivenFormComponent,
    EmailValidator
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule      
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'carpool'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('carpool');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span')?.textContent).toContain('carpool app is running!');
  });
});
```

**reactFormComponent.html**

```
<div class="login-comp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="outer-box">
            <h3 class="title">Reactive form</h3>
            <form [formGroup]="registerForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="">Name</label>
                    <input class=" form-control" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
                    <p *ngIf="(registerForm.get('firstName')?.dirty || 
                    registerForm.get('firstName')?.touched ) && 
                    registerForm.get('firstName')?.errors " 
                    class="alert alert-danger">This is required</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="">email</label>
                    <input class=" form-control" type="email" formControlName="email">
                    <p *ngIf="(registerForm.get('email')?.dirty || 
                    registerForm.get('email')?.touched ) && 
                    registerForm.get('email')?.errors " 
                    class="alert alert-danger">invalid</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset formGroupName="address">
                    <label class="">Steet</label>
                    <input class=" form-control" type="text" formControlName="street">
                    <label class="">Zip</label>
                    <input class=" form-control" type="text" formControlName="zip">
                    <label class="">City</label>
                    <input class=" form-control" type="text" formControlName="city">
                </fieldset>
                
                </div>
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="subForm()">Submit</button>
                
            </form>
            <div [hidden]="!submittedForm">
                <p>Name: {{registerForm.get('firstName')?.value}}</p>
                <p>Name: {{registerForm.get('email')?.value}}</p>
                <p>Street: {{registerForm.get('address.street')?.value}}</p>
                <p>City: {{registerForm.get('address.city')!.value}}</p>
                <p>zip: {{registerForm.get('address.zip')!.value}}</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

**reactFormComponent.ts**

````
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-react-form',
  templateUrl: './react-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./react-form.component.css']
})
export class ReactFormComponent implements OnInit {

  registerForm!:FormGroup;
   submittedForm!:boolean;
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['',Validators.required],
      email: ['', validateEmail],
        address: this.formBuilder.group({
          street:[],
          zip:[], 
          city:['',Validators.required]
        }) 
    });
  }
  subForm() {
    this.submittedForm=true;
    console.log(this.registerForm);
  }
}

function validateEmail(eid:FormControl):any {
  let email_regex=/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return email_regex.test(eid.value)?null : {
    emailInvalid: {
      message: 'Invalid Format'
    }
  };
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates the test module created in `app.component.spec.ts` cannot find the provider for `FormBuilder`.

`FormBuilder` is defined in the `FormsModule`. You will notice that it is imported in `AppModule` (which is why your app compiles and runs) but it is not imported in `configureTestingModule` in `app.component.spec.ts`.

Fix:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,               // << ----- add this line
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
```

Comment: I tried this. Still facing the same issues.

Comment: Sorry, can't see anything else that could cause it.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the `app.component.spec.ts`, but in `<your-component-name>.spec.ts` you've got to add those:

```
        imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
        ],
        providers: [<your-providers>],
        declarations: [<your-component-name>],
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be the answer! I tried to follow the each answer, but it doesn't event answer the problem.. I don't know that spec.ts has this function for a component/unit testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,               // << ----- add this line
        ReactiveFormsModule        // You should add this too
      ],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue with below code in test...

```
 imports: [
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
 ],
 providers: [FormBuilder],
```

But after that I also got different error

```
 Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?).
```

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74783209/3663854), I have later on opted to include this in my "tsconfig.spec.json" file. I am using Angular 14. It appear I need to refactor the application code itself, but for now I choose to not do it and set this in test tsconfig file instead.

```
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {    
  "useDefineForClassFields": false
},
```

Posting these 2 separate solution as some might encounter these chain of error too... hope this help!