# Angular 15 - FormsBuilder - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'group')

Tags: angular, forms, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular15

I migrated my project to Angular 15 and can no longer directly use the FormsBuilder for Reactive Forms. I get an undefined exception:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'group')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'group')
```

This is my code:

```
 settingsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    locations: ''
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
```

Everything worked fine before. A solution that works is via the lifecycle hook NgOnInit. However, that would be the non-recommended way and I lose my implicit typing.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Are you positive this is the site of your error? Here's a [Stackblitz of this working in Angular 15](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjgaah?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: If I dump everything in NgOnInit it works. I don't know what else could be causing the problem.

Comment: Direct instantiation now works for me: settingsForm = new FormBuilder().nonNullable.group({...}); - However, it is strange why it does not work DI and constructor. I couldn't reproduce the error either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for your issue is the tsconfig switch [`useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields).

When this is enabled, classes are initialized as defined in the ecma-standard, where the initialization order is a little different to typescript. See also the [TS 3.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier)

So, when this is on, the field `settingsForm` is initialized *before* the constructor shorthands.

From my research I believe that this will be the default behaviour in future versions of typescript, so you should refactor your code accordingly.

```
// useDefineForClassFields = true
"use strict";
class Test {
    foo;
    bar = this.foo;
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        console.log(this.foo, this.bar);
    }
}
const x = new Test('abc');
```

```
// useDefineForClassFields = false
"use strict";
class Test {
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = this.foo;
        console.log(this.foo, this.bar);
    }
}
const x = new Test('abc');
```

Generated on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNH0AOATgJYBuYS80ARmAdALzRIAWREAdAGYD23A3Fiy5owbgDtkBAK7Ak3AgApCpcpR7cAXNElExAcwCUaIcNyiJ3EPHYhuehSzZdeAGiasONAgYHZcAXyxAzCxzZGgADwZoMXgAdzhEJAUAcjAqYBSfIA)

Comment: Interesting! Just strange that I can't get it reproduced with a new Angular 15 app and the problem only occurred when migrating my Angular 14 -> 15 App.. I rearranged my code and then leave it as it is. I'll still be happy to test your TS configuration later to see if it's the problem.